# Accessing Item index inside ListView item

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm using a NativeScript list, and I wan't to display the item index inside a list item. But, I can't find a way to achieve this. My code looks like this:

```
        <StackLayout>
            <Label class="h2 card-title" text="Exercise"></Label>
            <ListView class="list-group" seperatorHeight="0" separatorColor="black"
                [items]="statisticService.exercises" [nsRouterLink]="['../exercise', 3]" itemTemplateSelector="index">
                <ng-template let-item="item">
                    <Label [text]="item.name" class="h3 my-list-group-item"></Label>
                </ng-template>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

With regular Angular I could just use  `*ngFor="let exercise of statisticService.exercises; let i = index"` instead and then do `{{i}}`, but that doesn't seem to work with nativescript's listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let-i="index"` on your ng-template like described in the doc :

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listview